# How to create a table in adf with variable no of columns

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello I am developing a web application using ADF (jdeve11.1.2.4). I know how to populate a table programatically from this post [Programmatic ADF Table](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/11/populate-aftable-programmatically-from.html)

But in the above post the no of columns are fixed (It is bean structure). But I cannot use the above post. Because I need to create a table with 'n' no-of columns. Means Columns are not fixed. Some times the columns may be 4 or some times the columns may be 7 and what ever it may be. Suppose I have two sqls and both contains differnt no of columns.

```
Ex: (suppose student is a table)
   select id from student
   select id,name from student
```

so in the above two sqls no of columns are diffent. I need to show the resul set of the above queries in a tablular format.

Please help me how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if declarative mode view objects would help? Blog [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/declarative_view_objects_vos_for). So the query is not built until the UI is gen'd. You could dynamically generate the table and insert columns and then bind to the VO.

Comment: Joe's idea is the right design here, provided you are always retrieving data from the same table (joined tables) and only columns change.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite complex to do and it may require some extra study:

1. create a programatic view object by passing your sql statement using:

   ApplicationModuleImpl.createViewObjectFromQueryStmt(java.lang.String voName,java.lang.String query)
2. try to construct af:columns in a loop:

```html
<af:table value="#{bindings.EmployeesView1.collectionModel}" .. id="t1">
  <af:iterator id="i1" value="#{bindings.EmployeesView1.attributesModel.attributes}" var="column" rows="0">
    <af:column headerText="#{column.label}" id="c1">
      <af:outputText id="d1" attributeModel="#{column}" value="#{row.bindings[column.name].inputValue}" />
    </af:column>
  </af:iterator>
</af:table>
```

Comment: Thanks for you time. Let me try with this. I ll get back to you with status.